# Two Rocker Switch Installation

Tags: switch

I’m in Florida and a hurricane passed by last night. I woke up to my front porch light blinking on and off and one of the rocker switches clicking. I’m assuming a short or arc somewhere so I swapped out the bulb and grabbed two new rocker switches.

As I removed the two old switches, I encountered something I’m not experienced with. It appears that only one line comes in and jumpers are used between the two switches. Should I wire the new ones the same way?[image]

Comment: I am quite sure that bare is suppose to go on the green screws.  There should be a white wire on the silver screw, if they are smart switches.  Having a black jumping to the other switch is okay.  The bare red wire is not okay.  It goes somewhere or needs to be capped with a wire nut.

Comment: If this is your only hurricane damage, congrats!

Answer (score 5):

I'm noticing a red wire which appears to have come loose.

I think that may be the crux of your problem.

Find the other 3-way switch and review the installation instructions for Zwave.  Look at how travelers are wired, and try correcting the loose wire before you decide the switches are dead.

Answer (score 4):

Shared incoming hot wire is OK if done properly. That means one of:

- Screw to clamp (**not regular screw**) holding one wire on each side
- Pigtails - incoming wire attaches to two short wires with a wire nut and the other end of each short wire attaches to the switch

It is not clear from the picture how the two wires are connected to the first switch, so that may need fixing.

But you've got some real problems here. The obvious one is **neutral**. Or rather, lack thereof. This switch [requires neutral, see the manual](https://products.z-wavealliance.org/ProductManual/File?folder=&filename=Manuals/2643/14289%20-%20Cap%20Touch%20Manual.pdf). Instead of neutral (white wire) connected to each neutral screw, you have bare ground wires connected. Those should be attached to the green ground screws.

The good news is that it looks like you have a neutral bundle in the back of the box. Assuming you do, add two white wires as pigtails to that bundle. You will likely need a larger wire nut. Each white wire connects to a neutral screw on a switch.

Of course, if you are replacing with dumb switches then you won't need neutral. But most switches with WiFi or other wireless control, motion sensor or other smarts need neutral, as do some dimmers.

There are *some* switches which are designed to allow using ground instead of neutral if neutral is not available. That does not appear to be the case here, and even if it was you would be required to use neutral if it is available. I suspect the original installer looked at wires on the previous dumb switches and hooked them up "the same" as best as they could, without looking at the installation manual.

Comment: It was working before hurricane ! did the hurricane remove the Neutral ?

Comment: @Ruskes The hurricane probably caused a power surge that messed up the electronics. That happens. The hurricane didn't remove the neutral - it has been wrong since the switches were originally installed. My point is: **the existing installation violates manufacturer instructions and the NEC**. I am 100% aware that ground used as neutral on a low-current device (the current here is probably a few watts to run the switch, not the current used by the lighting) will 100% function properly. But it is not safe under certain situations - the kinds of things that can go wrong in storms and stuff...

Comment: @Ruskes are you suggesting that the OP should ignore the blatant violation of using ground as neutral, when there's apparently an easy fix by tapping into the existing neutral bundle at the back of the box?

Comment: @brhans see my answer

Comment: @Ruskes I'm responding to your comment here on this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you paid attention when buying replacement.

The one on the right is a dimmer switch model ZW3009

The one on the left is a relay switch model ZW4005

They are both ZWAVE type (remote control)

In any case the original wiring might have worked for a while before hurricane but it is wrong.

They used the Ground (naked coper) as Neutral.

Connect the blacks as they were.

Connect the Ground to the marked Ground screw (on top of the switches).

From the wire nut (with bundle of whites) bring a white wire to the switches and connect where the old ground was.